# How can I iterate the row of table and append result of each iteration

Tags: sql, postgresql

Assume I have a product table which has fields id, color and size.
I am trying to cluster the product with the same color and size.

```
select count(*) as product_count, color, size from product group by color, size
```

for each record in above table, I would like to get all the product ids with the same color&size.

And I would like to save the result into a csv file.
The result will be sth like

```
color red, size 9:
id1, id2, id3, id4
color yellow, size 8:
id6, id7
...
```

Is there a way to do this in postgreSQL?

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate the IDs by color and size:

```
select color, size, 
       array_agg(id order by id)
from product
group by color, size;
```

Or if you want a single "readable" string:

```
select concat('Color ', color, 'Size ', size, 
              ': ', string_agg(id::text, ','))
from product
group by color, size;
```